# Sum Range Loop to the Last column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a loop in VBA on a PivotTable to SUM all the rows to the last column. I know I need to make the sum with the range because the PovitTable is adding new columns and rows. I have this code but it just static, I would like it to make dynamic with the loop.

````
Dim Celd As Object, Rang As Range, LastCol As Long

 LastCol = Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Select

   ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Total"

Set Rang = Range("D6:D16") ------------------ Here it should be the last column 

For Each Celd In Rang

Celda.Value = Celda.Offset(0,-2).Value + Celda.Offset(0,-1).Value ----------------------- Need to change the SUM 

Next Celd ```

Sorry, This code is static. Could someone help me with this loop. I'm new in BVA
````

Comment: Seems like something you can do with Pivot Tables grand totals. Why do you need to loop?

Comment: I need a loop for summing all the rows on the range

Comment: Still unclear to my why the grant totals in a pivot won’t do this

Comment: The total of the rows should be on the last column, however the PivotTable is changing adding values every time that you refresh the Excel Sheet. I was thinking to make first a range until the last column, and everything in that range make a SUM. the loop is to make for summing all the rows. The PivotTable doesn't have a column with the grand totals is dynamic

Comment: pivot tables, by design, are dynamic. I don't think your question is clear (or it could just be me.) I would consider adding some sample data (show table in current state and show what you want your output to be based on that table)

Comment: Read up on `PivotTable` Properties, such as [`PivotTable.DataBodyRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable.databodyrange).  Or the Non-VBA [`GETPIVOTDATA` function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/getpivotdata-function-8c083b99-a922-4ca0-af5e-3af55960761f)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the last column a number of ways. One way is by using

```
LastColumn = Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.Count
```

Which returns the last column as a long value. I prefer this method because it will work even if you have a blank column or blank row. You can use String concatenation to set the rang variable:

```
Set rang = Range("D6:" & LastColumn & "16")
```

If you just want the sum of all the rows/columns you can use

```
mySum = Application.Sum(rang)
```

The sum will be stored in the mySum variable.

Comment: Thank you, great help to have a better understanding. Still stuck on the code

Comment: From what I understand from your post and comments you should only need these 3 lines of code, and maybe an output (if you don't have that already). You may have to adapt it slightly - for instance if you wanted to use sheet 2 instead of sheet 1 - but you shouldn't need a loop at all.